# How can I set different background images for different li with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, css-selectors

I currently have a Joomla 3 site that I am building and I am trying to add social icons using the module SP Tabs so that you can click on 3 different tabs to give you information such as latest news, twitter and other news within the same area.

I have managed to change the look from the tabs to social icon images but the problem I have is that I have only been able to change 2 of the images and the third one is reusing the 2nd image already displayed.

The following is a snapshot (HTML + CSS) from Firebug as my site is currently on my localhost.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sptab121" class="sptab_red">
    <div class="tabs_buttons">
      <div class="tabs_mask">
        <ul class="tabs_container">
          <li class="tab first-tab active></li>
          <li class="tab"></li>
          <li class="tab"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sptab121 .tabs_mask, #sptab121 ul.tabs_container li span {
    height: 105px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
#sptab121 .tabs_mask {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 100px 0px 5px;
}
#sptab121 .tabs_mask {
    line-height: 0px !important;
}

#sptab121 ul.tabs_container {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

#sptab121 .first-tab {
    background: transparent url("/images/twitter.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 50px 55px !important;
    float: left;
    line-height: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 55px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 23px 0px 0px;
    width: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#sptab121 ul.tabs_container li.tab {
    background: transparent url("/images/local.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 50px 55px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 55px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 23px 0px 0px;
    width: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is that the class the 2nd and 3rd `li` use is the same one "tab". I have managed to override the first class by adding a class for the first tab but I am not sure how I can use a different image for the 2nd and 3rd link.

The other problem is that its not as easy as adding "second tab" next to the `li` class as the module has been coded in JavaScript and I have not been able to find the code where this is implemented.

Any advice on how I could change this will be really appreciated.

The link for the Joomla Module: "extensions.joomla.org/extension/sp-tab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pseudo class

```
#sptab121 ul.tabs_container li.tab {
    background: transparent no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 50px 55px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 55px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 23px 0px 0px;
    width: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}    
#sptab121 ul.tabs_container li.tab:nth-child(2){ 
    background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-icons/4096/instagram-4096-black.png") ;
    }
    #sptab121 ul.tabs_container li.tab:nth-child(3){  
    background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/80-google-plus-512.png") ;
    }
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0tt7qkur/)**